# How to get a validating attribute name from a property in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using model validation in a class and I have used attributes in few properties. I have already get the attributes name by property name but it gives me all attributes from a property but I need only that attribute name which  got error like ex- if Required attribute fires then it should give only me Required attribute name not all attributes.I am sharing my code and thanks in advance.

```
public class ProductModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Product Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Quantity")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Numeric Values in Quantity")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value greater than 0")]
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
}

public static bool IsFormValid()
{
    var model="ProductModel";     
    var errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var context = new ValidationContext(model);
    bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, errors, true);
    
    if (isValid == false)
    {
        ShowValidationFields(errors, model);
    }
    return errors.Count() == 0;
}

private static void ShowValidationFields(List<ValidationResult> errors, object model)
{
   
    if (model == null) { return; }
   
    foreach (var error in errors)
    {          
        var PropName = error.MemberNames.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
        Type type = model.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType;
        
        var Validation = type.GetProperty(PropName).GetCustomAttributes(false)
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.GetType().Name, a => a);

        --here i am getting all attributes name  assign in a property
    }                                                       
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the issue, but the `errors` collection contains the "offending" properties. Can you use that to retrieve the specific property which failed validation?

Comment: I think he wants the offending attribute name only, but reflection ain't gonna do it.

Comment: @ShaiCohen yes the errors collection only contain offending properties and yes i can get the name of the property and attribute error msg but i want to get the attribute name also like (Required,RegularExpression)

Comment: @insane_developer yes you r right i only want to offending attribute name only but **Validation** gives me all attributes name

Comment: @PrashantSharma ValidationResult gives you the member(s) that had validation errors. It doesn't provide you with the explicit attribute that triggered the error. Using reflection on that member will not do a thing for you, other than list all of its attributes.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you need this? Perhaps there's a better solution for you

Comment: @insane_developer is there is any solution i can filter only explicit attribute  from all attributes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing on your work in `ShowValidationFields`.

Retrieve only the `ValidationAttributes` from the concerning property.

```
var validationAttributes = type.GetProperty(PropName).GetCustomAttributes<ValidationAttribute>();
```

Then, to find the `ValidationAttribute` that has an error, you can (only) do a match on the error message between the `ValidationResult` (`error`) and `ValidationAttribute`.

```
var validationAttributeWithError = 
    validationAttributes.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ErrorMessage == error.ErrorMessage);

var attributeName = validationAttributeWithError.GetType().Name;
```

In case the `RequiredAttribute` on `ProductName` has errors, `attributeName` will contain the `string` value `RequiredAttribute`.

Comment: in **validationAttributeWithError** i only get the errormsg but still did not get the attribute name and   in **validationAttributes ** i got all attributes

Comment: @PrashantSharma Updated my post with how the retrieve the attribute name.