# In ASP.NET Core Web API, how do I find which data annotation(s) failed for a property in ModelState

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, modelstate

I have the following model defined

```
public class User
{
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The Email Address is not valid.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an email address.")]
    [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "The Email Address must be less than 5 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address:")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when the incoming http post request has following payload, which doesn't satisfy two data annotations such as `StringLength` and `EmailAddress`, how do I find out which data annotations failed for the property `EmailAddress`?

```
{
    "EmailAddress": "Raj.xyz.com"
}
```

I could not find anything in ModelState which would let me know what are the data annotations failed.

Comment: Email address should be in this format "abc@xyz.com" or "Raj@xyz.com'

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67098165/how-to-get-a-validating-attribute-name-from-a-property-in-c-sharp) might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you run validation by yourself using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator`.

Then your code would look like:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

var user = new User()
{
    EmailAddress = "Raj.xyz.com"
};

var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
Validator.TryValidateObject(user, new ValidationContext(user), validationResults, true);

var errors = validationResults
    .Select(x => $"Members: '{string.Join("', ", x.MemberNames)}'\nError: {x.ErrorMessage}\n");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", errors));

public class User
{
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The Email Address is not valid.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an email address.")]
    [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "The Email Address must be less than 5 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address:")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

> Check out the result: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ndgzmp

---

The code prints the output to the console:

> Members: 'EmailAddress'
> Error: The Email Address is not valid.
>
> Members: 'EmailAddress'
> Error: The Email Address must be less than 5 characters.

---

As you can see, you pass a `List<ValidationResult>` to the `Validator`. It fills the list with validation errors.

`ValidationResult` instance has:

- `.MemberNames` property that indicates the property names which failed validation,
- `.ErrorMessage` property that provides a human-readable error that can be shown to an end-user.

---

If you do it in Web API, you need:

1. Create your validation filter and get access to the `ModelState`:

   ```cs
   public class ValidationFilter : IActionFilter
   {
       public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
       {
           if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               // Here you have access to the `ModelState`
               context.Result = new UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(context.ModelState);
           }
       }

       public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
       {
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add DI registrations:

   ```cs
   // Register your validation filter in the DI
   builder.Services.AddScoped<ValidationFilter>();
   // Disable implicit validation
   builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options => options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true);
   ```
3. Put filter on your controller:

   ```cs
    ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidationFilter))]
   public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
   {
       [HttpPost(Name = "Post")]
       public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Product product)
       {
           return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
       }
   }
   ```